# Is it possible to install a new HP Envy-4520 printer on a computer running Snow Leopard

Tags: snow-leopard, printing

I am trying help someone setup a new printer (HP Envy-4520) on an older Mac (Snow Leopard 10.6.8) Obviously the best solution would be to replace the computer, unfortunately, this isn't an option. I am not onsite with the Mac at this time.

- I found instructions through Google, but they are obsolete*.
- The printer does work when printing from a mobile device.
- I have tried setting the printer up using the generic driver options, but they didn't work. (The printer received data, but gave an error message referring to the output tray extender).
- I can put together a Windows box from spare parts and share the printer from that, if that would work.
- I am experienced with Windows and Linux, but my Mac experience is limited.

Any suggestions or is this a lost cause?

*Instructions mentioned above: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printers-Archive-Read-Only/driver-for-envy-4520-with-OS-10-6-8/td-p/5385512, points to https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04510394, which points to https://123.hp.com, which just says "We’re sorry—We don’t support this operating system."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple's archived support article for supported printers](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT6198), the ‘HP ENVY 4500 e-All-in-One’ is supported by Mac OS X 10.6.8. I recommend downloading and installing the [most recent HP Printer Drivers (v2.16.1) for Mac OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1770) and see if the printer drivers for the HP ENVY 4500 e-All-in-One will work with the model you have.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try soon and report back.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Just to add a couple of details in case anyone else is trying this. The bundled installer utility didn't work, but when I added the printer and manually chose the 4500 driver, the printer worked. Didn't try the scanner.